# symfony no supporting normalizer found while normalizing an entity

Tags: symfony, normalization

I'm working on symfony 4.1. 
I defined two normalizer in my service.yml.

```
api.tone_normalizer:
    class: App\Serializer\Normalizer\JnToneNormalizer
    tags: [serializer.normalizer]
```

and

```
api.wskeytone_normalizer:
    class: App\Serializer\Normalizer\ApiWsKeyToneToneNormalizer
    tags: [serializer.normalizer]
```

Here the first normalizer. Is aware about JnTone entities.

```
<?php
namespace App\Serializer\Normalizer;


use App\Entity\JnTone;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;
/**
 * JnTone normalizer
 */
class JnToneNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = array())
    {

        return [
            'id'   => $object->getId(),
            'name' => $object->getName(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        return $data instanceof JnTone;
    }
}
```

And the normalizer where I want to call the first one. rootTone is an instance of JnTone entity so I want to call my JnTone normalizer.

```
<?php
namespace App\Serializer\Normalizer;


use App\Entity\JnWsKey;
use App\Entity\JnTone;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerAwareTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\SerializerAwareNormalizer;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerAwareTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerAwareInterface;
/**
 * JnWsKey normalizer
 */
class ApiWsKeyNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface, SerializerAwareInterface
{
    use NormalizerAwareTrait;
    use SerializerAwareTrait;

    private $tones;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = array())
    {


        return [
            'id'=>$object->getId(),
            'name'=>$object->getName(),
            'rootTone'=>$this->serializer->normalize($object->getRootTone(),$format,$context)

        ];



    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        return $data instanceof JnWsKey ;
    }



}
```

I can't get this working. The first normalizer isn't find

```
Could not normalize object of type App\Entity\JnTone, no supporting normalizer found.
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did not realize that I have to declare all needed normailizer in the serializer definition. I solved it doing:

```
$encoder = new JsonEncoder();

$serializer = new Serializer(array(

    new JnToneNormalizer(),
    new JnWsKeyToneNormalizer()

), array($encoder));
```

Answer (score 1):

Symfony seems to have ObjectNormalizer. I think you may take advantage of it. Check the [installation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#installation) and [usage](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#usage). I think there is also a way to perform serialization of complex nested objects using annotations and groups.