# Symfony 4, Could not normalize object of type DateTime, no supporting normalizer found

Tags: symfony, serialization, symfony4

I'm trying to normalize the responses of my controllers and most of them work except for this one because it has a DateTime object. This is the class Touch:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use DateTime;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TouchRepository")
 */
class Touch implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $time;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $toucher;

    private $accountId;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cabinet")
     */
    private $cabinet;

    /**
     * Touch constructor.
     * @param DateTime $time
     * @param string $toucher
     * @param Cabinet $cabinet
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function __construct(DateTime $time, string $toucher, Cabinet $cabinet = null, int $id = null)
    {
        $this->time = $time;
        $this->toucher = $toucher;
        $this->cabinet = $cabinet;
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(int $id): self
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTime(): DateTime
    {
        return $this->time;
    }

    public function getToucher(): string
    {
        return $this->toucher;
    }

    public function getCabinet(): Cabinet
    {
        return $this->cabinet;
    }

    public function setCabinet(Cabinet $cabinet): self
    {
        $this->cabinet = $cabinet;
        $this->accountId = $cabinet->getId();
        return $this;
    }

    public function getAccountId(): int
    {
        return $this->accountId;
    }

    public function setAccountId(int $accountId): self
    {
        $this->accountId = $accountId;

        return $this;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

And I made a normalizer, `TouchNormalizer.php`, for it as follows:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Normalizer;

use App\Entity\Touch;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;

class TouchNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface
{

    /**
     * Normalizes an object into a set of arrays/scalars.
     *
     * @param Touch $object Object to normalize
     * @param string $format Format the normalization result will be encoded as
     * @param array $context Context options for the normalizer
     *
     * @return array|string|int|float|bool
     */

    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = []): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $object->getId(),
            'time' => $object->getTime(),
            'toucher' => $object->getToucher(),
            'cabinet' => $object->getCabinet(),
            'accountId' => $object->getAccountId()
        ];
    }


    /**
     * Checks whether the given class is supported for normalization by this normalizer.
     *
     * @param mixed $data Data to normalize
     * @param string $format The format being (de-)serialized from or into
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        return $data instanceof Touch && $format === 'json';
    }

}
```

Then in the controller, `TouchController`, I have this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Repository\TouchRepository;
use App\Entity\Bedroom;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use App\Http\SerializedJsonResponse;
use App\Normalizer\TouchNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;

class TouchController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/Bedroom/{bedroomId}/touchs", methods={"GET"})
     * @param \App\Controller\AuthenticationController $apiKeyAuthenticator
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Bedroom $bedroomId
     * @param TouchRepository $touchRepository
     * @return SerializedJsonResponse
     */
    public function AuthenticateAPI(AuthenticationController $apiKeyAuthenticator, Request $request, Bedroom $bedroomId, TouchRepository $touchRepository)
    {
        $AuthenticatorObject = $apiKeyAuthenticator->checkAuthentication($request);
        if (isset($AuthenticatorObject['success'])) {
            return new SerializedJsonResponse(new Serializer([new TouchNormalizer()], [new JsonEncoder()]), $touchRepository->findTouchsByAccount($bedroomId));
        }
        return new SerializedJsonResponse(new Serializer([new TouchNormalizer()], [new JsonEncoder()]), $AuthenticatorObject, 401);
    }
}
```

This returns the aforementioned error:

> Could not normalize object of type DateTime, no supporting normalizer found.

I tried using the DateTimeNormalizer by replacing `TouchNormalizer` by `DateTimeNormalizer` but this returns the time in an odd form, namely:

```
"time": "2019-06-12T09:51:22+00:00,"
```

instead of the original

```
        "time": {
            "date": "2019-06-12 09:51:22.000000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "UTC"
        },
```

How could I keep my original DateTime format and normalize the DateTime object properly?

Comment: Hello, i see in other post same error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52341427/symfony-no-supporting-normalizer-found-while-normalizing-an-entity, the difference is your new Serializer. Maybe an error ? Other link for DateTimeNormalizer : https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-datetime-normalizer

Comment: @GaryHoubre Hi and thanks for linking those two links. I have checked both of them before posting and non of them achieved what I was trying to do, namely keeping the original form. The closest I could get is this `"time": "2019-06-12 11:51:22"` but couldn't keep the timezone type and timezone. Or did I miss something?

Comment: can you replace this : "new Serializer([new TouchNormalizer()], [new JsonEncoder()])" with : "new Serializer([new TouchNormalizer(), new JsonEncoder()])"

Comment: If i find an other possibility, i tell you :)

Comment: @GaryHoubre This gives another error: 
> Serialization for the format json is not supported

Comment: The original format looks exactly like `var_dump($date)`, so my guess is that it was being picked up by `ObjectNormalizer`. Question is: why do you want to keep that? It's php specific, while the 'odd' format is the well known and standard [ISO8601](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php#datetime.constants.types) used pretty much everywhere.

Comment: @msg The plan was to do stuff with the timezones. So I could work with multiple timezones. But maybe it's indeed better to do it in another way.

Comment: Try this syntax: `new Serializer([new TouchNormalizer(), new DateTimeNormalizer()], [new JsonEncoder()])`. You can also use `ObjectNormalizer`.

Comment: @msg Still the same thing unfortunately.